# Web and cross platform development with Intel XDK

Tags: javascript, html, cross-platform, web-deployment, intel-xdk

I'm planning to make a responsive website with JavaScript and HTML5 but would need camera access on mobile devices. JavaScript and HTML5 alone don't allow this.
Today i read about Intel XDK and was all like "niiiiccceee, wooooww" but then realized that they only write about mobile development. Most important i want to develop a responsive website.

*hint: i'm completely new to JavaScript, HTML5, Webdevelopment.... (not new to development! I can work with Java, C, C++, Prolog, Haskell)*

**Question:** Is it possible to develop a website with Intel XDK and additionally for mobile devices to use native functions? Or do i have this right at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel XDK is a tool that will let you use web languages (HTML/Javascript/CSS) to develop native applications for a variety of platforms.

It is **not** a tool for developing websites. If something isn't allowed on the web, then no tool is going to magically allow you to bypass these security restrictions.

Luckily, you *should* be able to access the mobile device's camera as explained [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/). But it's still subject to whether it's supported/allowed by whatever browsing the client is using.

If native functions are crucial for your project, then deploying a native app with Intel XDK would allow you access to whatever you need, but then it won't be a website anymore.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. It seems that i misread the fact that Intel XDK is for native app development **only**. Eventually i should stay with my responsive design concept and just do it per image / file upload.